# Отправка собственных сообщений с одного приложения на другое

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть два приложения. В первом приложении по нажатию кнопки, должна нарисоваться фигура во втором приложении. Но для этого, как я понимаю, нужны собственные сообщения, которые бы я передавал из одного приложения в другое, а там их обрабатывал. Знаю, что надо использовать функцию `RegisterWindowMessage()` но как - я не знаю. Хотелось бы видеть пример, где будет:

- отправка сообщения из первого приложения во второе;
- регистрация собственного сообщения во втором приложении;
- обработка этого сообщения во втором приложении (где и как).

Comment: На Windows у вас 2 способа: RPC(DCOM), или сокеты. А так вопрос попадает прения.

Comment: посмотрите тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications

Comment: Можно послать сообщение WM_COPYDATA